# Thin flat cabinet door pull that mounts on the edge of the door rather than the face

Tags: cabinets, doorknob, knobs

I vaguely recall long ago seeing flat plastic or metal door pulls that mount to the edge of the door rather than the front face of the door. The long front protruding edge of the pull is rounded for better grasp.

These are meant for cabinet doors that mount flush to the edge of the cabinet rather than closing on the outside of the cabinet. They lend a sleek modern minimalist look.

Am I crazy or do these exist?

If they exist, where/how might I get some? What are they called?

I searched HomeDepot.com web site, and asked two human staffers, but no luck.

Comment: continuous edge pulls ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=continuous+edge+pulls&iax=images&ia=images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Edge pull

I think you might be referencing what is commonly called an **edge pull**. There are many manufacturers, each with their own selection of styles and finishes. This one (not an endorsement) is made by a fairly steady cabinet hardware company called Amerock:

[image]

Comment: I purposely did not include information on where to procure them, as shopping questions are off-topic in this forum. But now you know what they are called and can make appropriate internet searches (or better yet, visit a high-end lumber and hardware shop, **not Home Despot**.

Answer (score 1):

[Answer by Jimmy Fix-it](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/196444/21846) is correct.

## Tab pull

*Tab pull* is another name and variation.

[image: Photo of a tab pull]

Comment: I like the steel ones - cleaning and not likely to crack with flexing due to continuous heavy use.